# Cannot fix python invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
import time
print("hello, do you want to play this detective game?")
choice == input( "Yes or no?")
if choice 'no' :
    print: "ok then, bye"
    exit

if choice'yes':
    start
    name == input("Enter your name")
    print("hello, " + name ", in this game you are a famous detective handling a theft case."
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" you have gone on a holiday but ended up lost in the forest. you see a man walking up to you")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("man:' hi there! you seem quite lost! Do you want to stay the night with me?'")
    print(" you said:'why should i? i dont even know you'")
    print(" man : ' Do as you please, but if you stay in the forest for the night here's a friendly warning: there's wild wolves in the forests.'")
    choose == input( "stay the night or refuse?" )
    if choose "refuse":
          print("man: ' boy, you are stubborn!")
          print( "the man walks away, leaving you behind" + " In the end, you got eaten by the wolves due to your stubborness. THE END")
          choice == input("do you want to play again? yes or no?")
          if choice "yes":
          start
          if choice "no":
          print( "ok then, bye!")
          exit
```

Basically my question is this ' invalid syntax' at the upper [do you want to play? ] 'no' response.

But **when I erase it the problem goes to the next line**. It is very annoying and i cant find how to solve it.

I tried changing between ' and " but the result is still the same.

I would be glad if any of you would take the time to response as i just started yesterday and is still not very clear about invalid syntax.

Comment: You need a closing parens on this line? `print("hello, " + name ", in this game you are a famous detective handling a theft case."` - Why is this not like your other print statements? `print: "ok then, bye"` --- Basically you need to be a **lot** more careful in typing **exactly** what you are copying from. Close is not good enough. You need to be exact.

Comment: too many of wrong syntax I would recommend pycharm or any other IDE

Comment: Your code has many very basic errors. Some lines are far from being Python. Sorry, but I guess you will have to go through the tutorial again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice 'no' :
```

is the culprit (and same problem on line 8 and elsewhere). The expression requires a `==` to make:

```
if choice == 'no' :
```

However, line 3 will cause a problem before you get there - `choice` is not defined. `==` is a logical operator, it does not mean assignment as the code would seem to need to do at that point. Change it to perform assignment with `=`:

```
choice = input( "Yes or no?")
```

Also, it's better to test against lower case because you don't know what combination of upper and lower case characters might be entered by the user:

```
if choice.lower() == 'no' :
```

Line 9 reads `start` - again. Perhaps you mean that as a comment? If so add a `'#'` at the start of the line.

These problems are the tip of the iceberg. Perhaps you should read a few tutorials and code in small iterative increments to build up your program.

Comment: This answer doesn't even get close to solving all the syntax errors and other problems in the code. There must be well over a dozen of them.

Comment: @ekhumoro: gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: I think the OP needs to start by learning how to read tracebacks. If they try to "solve" the problems by deleting any lines that raise exceptions, they're not going to have much code left (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time

def game()

     print("hello, do you want to play this detective game?")

     choice == input( "Yes or no?")

     if choice == 'no' :

         print("ok then, bye")

         break
     if choice == 'yes':

         name == input("Enter your name")

         print("hello, " + name ", in this game you are a famous detective handling a theft case."
         time.sleep(1)
         print(" you have gone on a holiday but ended up lost in the forest. you see a man walking up to you")
         time.sleep(1)
         print ("man:' hi there! you seem quite lost! Do you want to stay the night with me?'")
         print(" you said:'why should i? i dont even know you'")
         print(" man : ' Do as you please, but if you stay in the forest for the night here's a friendly warning: there's wild wolves in the forests.'")
         choose == input( "stay the night or refuse?" )
         if choose == "refuse":
               print("man: ' boy, you are stubborn!")
               print( "the man walks away, leaving you behind" + " In the end, you got eaten by the wolves due to your stubborness. THE END")

               choice == input("do you want to play again? yes or no?")
               if choice == "yes":
                    game()
               if choice == "no":
                    print("ok then, bye!")
                    break
         else:
               #continue your game here
```

Hope this works! This might be better.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

issues:

1. `choice == input()` is wrong make it `choice = input()`
2. `choice 'no' :` is again in many place wrong make it `choice == 'no'`
3. `start`/`exit` is not required
4. `print()` function must have closing parenthesis

**fixed code:**

```
import time
def my_game():
    print("hello, do you want to play this detective game?")
    choice = input( "Yes or no?")
    if choice == 'no' :
        print("ok then, bye")

    if choice == 'yes':
        name = input("Enter your name")
        print("hello, " + name + ", in this game you are a famous detective handling a theft case.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(" you have gone on a holiday but ended up lost in the forest. you see a man walking up to you")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("man:' hi there! you seem quite lost! Do you want to stay the night with me?'")
        print(" you said:'why should i? i dont even know you'")
        print(" man : ' Do as you please, but if you stay in the forest for the night here's a friendly warning: there's wild wolves in the forests.'")
        choose = input( "stay the night or refuse?" )
        if choose == "refuse":
            print("man: ' boy, you are stubborn!")
            print( "the man walks away, leaving you behind" + " In the end, you got eaten by the wolves due to your stubborness. THE END")
            choice = input("do you want to play again? yes or no?")
            if choice == "yes":
                my_game()

            if choice == "no":
                print( "ok then, bye!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_game()
```